# What thing is responsible for Android - SQLite access?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm building a functional architecture.

With regard to the following android application framework diagram [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/basics/what-is-android.html), I'm wondering which software component at the android application framework layer would be responsible for providing the SQLite interface? I know that the android.database package gives the developer the necessary API to access the underlying SQLite database, but if we think of the "application framework layer", where is this provided? For example, the "Notification Manager" allows applications to display custom alerts. What component gives us database access? The reason I ask is for the purposes of documentation. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQLite API is deliberately not a component of the Application Framework Layer. It's a library. Like the other libraries, it can (theoretically) be used by any of the Application Framework components, but it's intended mainly for use by your application classes.

If you **must** map it into the Application Framework layer, you could say it's under the "Content Providers" bubble, but I think that would be more misleading than helpful.

Comment: Hi Dan. Thanks for your reply. So if you could put me wise - If I write an application, I assume it will reside at the "applications" layer. The classes that I write will leverage the android sdk libraries. I assume that allow the combined logic in my classes will leverage the various facets of the "application framework" layer, correct? For the sake of my functional diagram, can I assume that if my application is using the SQLite database, I can directly link my application to the SQLite component defined in the "libraries" layer? Thanks again. I'm having trouble finding this info via google.

Comment: thanks again for the update. I understand that it would be misleading linking it to the content provides component because this is meant for sharing data between applications. In reality, what exactly happens when the SQLite library is leveraged by an application? Sorry if it seems like a silly question. But if you compare it to (for example) displaying a notification, the "notification manager" takes care of that directly. Regards

Comment: @Joeblackdev: I'd say your application "imports" rather than "links to" the SQLite API, but otherwise, yes. For what it's worth, there isn't a huge difference in my mind between an "Application Framework Component" and a "library". However, one key difference at least for this diagram is that the Components rely heavily on callbacks and notifications to interact with the application, meaning that they are often "in control" of such interactions. The libraries (as far as I know them) are more passive, and generally driven by the application -- i.e., they make much less use of callbacks.

Comment: @Joeblackdev: Your second comment showed up after I finished writing my first, but I think I answered both of yours there.